# Mapping ui:field in GWT to generated code

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to get some automated UI testing going on a GWT application and I'm having trouble finding a way to track UI elements.

For example, I have the following:

```
<g:Button text="Submit" ui:field="submitButton" enabled="true" />
```

which generates:

```
<button class="gwt-Button" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Its a compiler error to set both ui:field and id (id is considered deprecated anyway) so the problem is that I have no easy way to select my submit button using something like selenium.

Is anyone aware of a way I can map the

```
ui:field="sumbitButton"
```

to the generated HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After further investigation I've discovered that you can enable debugIds which are ment for testing purposes. If you add:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
```

to your *.gwt.xml file you can then set debugId on your ui elements as such:

```
<g:Button text="Submit" ui:field="submitButton" enabled="true" debugId="submitButton"/>
```

and also in the codebehind by using the ensure debug id method

```
submitButton.ensureDebugId("submitButton");
```

Comment: Hey. How are you clicking on this button with selenium? I tried few things, and I'm having problems with making selenium click the button!

Comment: I wasn't using selenium, but since this simply sets the Id on the element you should be able to select it in selenium based on Id.

Comment: Bear in mind that the generated debug id will be gwt-debug-submitButton

Comment: Put DebugInfo.setDebugIdPrefix("") in your onModuleLoad() to remove the gwt-debug- prefix from all IDs.