# How can I set id for GWT widgets in UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

In java  code we can set id. Is it possible to set 'id' for GWT widgets in UiBinder itself?

If it is possilbe please give me a sample.

Actually I tried the following code,

```
<g:Button ui:field="login" debugId="loginButton">
```

Then I checked it in alert. `Window.alert("Id: " + login.getElement().getId());`
But the output is `Id:`.

Id is not set for the login button

Is there any better way to do this?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check an availability of the following line in your module file (*.gwt.xml ):

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
```

And call the [ensureDebugId(Element, id)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html) method in your code:

```
login.ensureDebugId(login.getElement(), "loginButton");
```

Comment: With the Debug module inherited, you can also use the debugId attribute in uiBinder.xml like <g:HTMLPanel debugId="test">
By default, the element ID will then be gwt-debug-test. To remove the gwt-debug prefix, call DebugInfo.setDebugIdPrefix("") in your onModuleLoad().

Answer (score 4):

Adding ID is not possible.
This problem is also filed as a bug report and closed as "as designed". For details, see:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4176

But you can add a debugId if you add
`<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>` to your *.gwt.xml file.

See [Mapping ui:field in GWT to generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228153/mapping-uifield-in-gwt-to-generated-code)