# Add id to field with ui:field declaration

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to declare these elements in my UiBinder XML:

```
<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastName" ui:field="lastNameField" maxlength="150" />
```

Simply put, a label that is associated with a text input.

When I try to compile, however, I get this error:

> [ERROR] Cannot declare id="lastName" and ui:field="lastNameField" on the same element Element  (:23)

This seems like an idiotic restriction, especially since `ui:field` doesn't generate an ID. The only solution I've found so far is to assign the ID in the Java code itself like this:

```
@UiElement InputElement lastNameField;
...
lastNameField.setId("lastName");
```

This adds needless clutter to my Java. It also adds the complication that if this ID gets updated somewhere down the line, the `<label>` declaration in the XML will also need to be updated (and there's no @UiElement for the label, so it's pretty much completely invisible from the Java side.)

**Is there a way to add an ID to an element with a ui:field declaration from within the UiBinder XML itself?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UiBinder uses the ID to implement its `ui:field` magic, so no you can't set it from the XML.

The way to do it is to have a Java constant with the ID and use it from both sides:

```
@UiField(provided = true)
final String lastNameId = Document.get().createUniqueId();

@UiField InputElement lastNameField;

…

lastNameField.setId(LAST_NAME_ID);
```

and in the XML:

```
<ui:with field="lastNameId" type="java.lang.String"/>

…

<label for="{lastNameId}">Last Name:</label>
<input ui:field="lastNameField" maxlength="150"/>
```

Note that I haven't tested the above code with `type="java.lang.String"`, I've always used
a class containing various identifiers instead (or rather, an interface with a generator)

Alternatives are:

- if you can, use the alternate syntax for `<label>`:

  ```
  <label>Last Name: <input ui:field="lastNameField" maxlength="150"/></label>
  ```
- read the `for=""` value from Java to use it in `setId()`, that way at least you remove duplication, but you'll still have the issue that your IDs possibly won't be unique (as soon as you use your UiBinder-widget more than once)

  ```
  <label ui:field="lastNameLabel" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input ui:field="lastNameField" maxlength="150" />
  ```

  ```java
  @UiField LabelElement lastNameLabel;
  @UiField InputElement lastNameField;

  …

  lastNameField.setIf(lastNameLabel.getHtmlFor());
  ```

Comment: What about debugId's? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845544/how-can-i-set-id-for-gwt-widgets-in-uibinder

Comment: Debug-IDs are there for… debugging. Abusing tools rarely does good in the long-term.

Answer (score 4):

You may simplify Thomas' answer (a bit) by accessing the id in uibinder like this:

```
<b:ControlLabel for="{testTextBox.getId}">TextBox</b:ControlLabel>
<b:TextBox ui:field="testTextBox"></b:TextBox>

// In code behind:
@UiField(provided = true)
TextBox testTextBox = new TextBox();
...
testTextBox.setId("test");
this.initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
```

If you use GWT Bootstrap there is a handy feature that let's you wire up everything in xml  only:

```
<b:ControlLabel for="{testTextBox.getId}">TextBox</b:ControlLabel>
<b:TextBox ui:field="testTextBox" b:id="test"></b:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the section about gwt-bootstrap, it was extremely useful to me!

Answer (score 0):

`b:id="test"` works for all [gwtbootstrap3](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3) widgets.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is about vanilla GWT, not some bootstrap variant.

Comment: It's useful information. Bootstrap is very popular.

Comment: [gwtbootstrap](https://gwtbootstrap.github.io/)  and [gwtbootstrap3](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3) are two different libraries. They share the same functionality in this case, but that's not always the case. My post is about gwtbootstrap3, while he mentioned gwtbootstrap.