# UiBinder variables

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am fitting with UiBinder in gwt. I am using collapse uibinder (bootstrap library). I have the follow code:

```
<b:Collapse b:id="toggle1" existTrigger="true" ui:field="toggle1">
     <b:FluidRow>
           <b:Column size="12">
                <b:Alert close="false" animation="true" heading="Cabecera">
                    Text
                </b:Alert>
               </b:Column>
     </b:FluidRow>
 </b:Collapse>
```

My problem is I need change the b:id="toggle1" when I create it. I need use variable. Could someone explain me how to do it? I have looking on internet but I did not find a good explanation

Thank you very mucho in advice.

Comment: Do you need to change the id ("toggle1") or the attribute as a whole?

Comment: I need change only the id. If I want to have some different collapses each one should have diferentes idetifiers. 

I want to set id as a parameter, for example: id="{variable}" and form the java class set it.

Thanks Anders for answering so fast.

Comment: What is `b` here? How are you setting ID in XML? Please read [Add id to field with ui:field declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070979/add-id-to-field-with-uifield-declaration).

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry Braj for answering so late. I forgotten say that I was using bootstrap library. b is a part of its components.

Answer (score 1):

Set ID in JAVA after calling `createAndBindUi()`.

```
collapseWidget.getElement().setId("toggle2");
```

Steps to follow:

- Add below entry in you gwt.xml

  ```
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
  ```
- Use `debugId` along with `ui:field` as shown below in your `ui.xml`

  ```
  <gwt:CheckBox ui:field="myCheckBox" debugId="myCheckBox" />
  ```
- Now you can get the Id

  ```
  myCheckBox.getElement().getId();
  ```
- All the Ids are generated with default prefix `gwt-debug-` as shown below. If you want then you can remove it.

  ```
  gwt-debug-myCheckBox
  ```
- Use any one `getElement().setId()` or `ensureDebugId()`. The difference between them is prefixing with `gwt-debug-`. `ensureDebugId()` uses prefix.

---

Sample code: (Setting ID of `cancelButton` dynamically)

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiTemplate;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class MyDialogbox extends DialogBox {

    private static MyUiBinder myUIBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    @UiTemplate("MyDialogbox.ui.xml")
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyDialogbox> {
    }

    public MyDialogbox() {
        setWidget(myUIBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        System.out.println(cancelButton.getElement().getId());
        cancelButton.getElement().setId("cancel");
    }

    @UiField
    Button cancelButton;

    @UiHandler("cancelButton")
    void doOpenDialogBox(ClickEvent event) {
        hide();
    }

}
```

MyDialogbox.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

    <g:DialogBox autoHide="true" modal="false">
        <g:caption>
            <b>Caption text</b>
        </g:caption>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            Body text
            <g:Button ui:field='cancelButton' debugId='cancelButton'>Cancel</g:Button>
            <g:Button ui:field='okButton' debugId='okButton'>Okay</g:Button>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:DialogBox>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Read here about [gwt uibinder ui:with - calling methods with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937269/gwt-uibinder-uiwith-calling-methods-with-arguments).

Comment: Thanks! It is another way to do it. I will try it.