# My gwt application have components without ID,name. Is any way to set id/name (runtime) to components so i use them for testing in selenium?

Tags: java, gwt, selenium-ide

I Want to test application in Selenium IDE. But Id and name are not set for components used in GWT web application.
I develop test cases in Selenium IDE using XPATH and css.
I want way to set id/name (runtime) to components to develop testcases in Selenium IDE?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845544/how-can-i-set-id-for-gwt-widgets-in-uibinder

Answer (score 1):

You can set an ID on any widget:

```
myWidget.getElement().setId("123");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Id to the Widget, See the Below Example

```
Button b = new Button();
b.getElement().setId("mycustomid");
```