# Choosing between multiple ways to set GWT element IDs

Tags: java, css, gwt

As far as I can tell, there are two ways to set the IDs for web elements from within GWT. I need to perform Selenium automated testing, and would appreciate insight into the relative advantages of each technique.

**Option 1: the generally accepted method**

```
uiObject.ensureDebugId("idForMyElement");
```

This solution is well documented, and officially supported by google. However it comes with some disadvantages:

My team will have to add lines to every package's gwt.xml file like so:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.Debug' />
```

Furthermore, the Debug class prepends "gwt-debug" to IDs by default. I realize I can change this behavior, but I don't like adding complexity where I can help it.

**Option 2: use a generic setAttribute call**

```
uiObject.getElement().setAttribute("id", "idForMyElement);
```

This seems cleaner to me- are there any downsides I might be overlooking?

Relevant resources:
[How can I set id for GWT widgets in UiBinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845544/how-can-i-set-id-for-gwt-widgets-in-uibinder)
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4176

Comment: What do you want to do with the ids? Also the inherit has just to be added into your .gwt.xml

Comment: @user2248239 Automated testing using Selenium

Comment: Well a generic setAttribute call would do the same trick i guess but i don't see such a big advantage except that you won't have to add gwt-debug every time. Even if you take the setAttribute approach you have to prepare the gui elements anyway. And the debug prefix can also be removed with just one line of code anyway. So there is not such a big difference in complexity.

Comment: FYI: Here's a small class that will help you find element by their debug id using WebDriver: https://github.com/ArcBees/ArcBees-Common/blob/master/testutils/src/main/java/com/arcbees/test/ByDebugId.java

Comment: Thanks all. @user2248239 I saw an answer elsewhere that suggested I'd have to write my own replacement class, but a one-liner is no big deal.

Answer (score 3):

The first option is better because you can compile out debug ids from your production code, making it smaller.

With the second option ids will be there even when you don't need them anymore.